# Unable to use LabelEncoder pickle file in PowerBI

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, powerbi

I am deploying a python model in PowerBI. However, I am getting below error while running in PowerBI. I am not getting this error when using on training data.

```
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: ("This LabelEncoder instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.", 'occurred at index Column1')
```

I am doing label encoding as below.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(LabelEncoder)
#With this, you now retain all columns LabelEncoder as dictionary.
# Encoding the variable
fit = df.apply(lambda x: d[x.name].fit_transform(x))
# Using the dictionary to label future data
df.apply(lambda x: d[x.name].transform(x))
```

And I'm saving encoder with code below:

```
#Saving and loading a dictonary
import pickle
with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(a, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Loading label encoder as below.

```
with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    b = pickle.load(handle)
```

I'm encoding the unseen categories in real time data as 'Unavailable' which is presently handled in training dataset.
The same code works seamlessly well on validation set where I try loading saved LabelCoder and predicting.